# Software requirement using ASP.Net

Tags: asp.net, windows

My clients ask me to build a software for windows using asp. Its employment office and the software has to save the job seeker information and print the record. It will store the Resume of the job seeker and all personal details.

I don't know asp so I plan to give this to outside. I got two companies to work for this and both are saying different requirement. The office is having 5 computer and connected to LAN. I want to install the software in main computer and all the clients should access this.

One company is saying, you need to first download the database from the microsoft and install that then only you can use this appliation and you need to have IIS Server. Also, he is saying you cannot print on all the printer for this you have to configure the printer to software and they have to write the printer name in the software coding.

Other Company is saying, no need to install the database or IIS Server. The software itself install its own database. All your client computer can access the same database. Also you can print on any printer.

I cannot figure out who is correct and who is wrong. Please suggest me.

Comment: What you want to make Desktop Application or WebApplication ?

Comment: Desktop Application.

Answer (score 0):

Neither company is "wrong" they are answering different questions.  The first is telling you what would be required for this to be a web site, I'm sure based on the fact you are saying it is required to be asp.net (this is a web language only). The second answer is correct for a desktop application, built using either WinForms or WPF.  So neither answer is wrong, I think the problem comes in what kind of application this is.  You said in the comments that it was a desktop application, but you also say it has to be done in asp.net, well this is simply not possible since desktop applications are not built in asp.net. I think with some clarification on your part you will get similar answers from anyone who you propose this job to.

Comment: actually its visual studio. sorry. But both companies know its windows application. what about printer ?? one is saying only Epson and other is saying any printer i can use.

Comment: That really depends, I can't say with certainty either way.  I design so you can use any printer for most things however there are application that I require not only a specific make of printer but a specific model and set of settings.  I would have to know a lot more about the project before I could say.  It sounds like these companies are taking drastically different approaches to the application.